# maximum stored proc name in firebird

Tags: firebird, firebird2.1

I am migrating my db from Interbase to Firebird, and the 1st hiccup we hit comes from our stored proc names.

We have a handful of stored procedures with names greater than 31 characters (which appears to be the max in FB 2.1.3)

Is there a way to increase this limitation? It will be a far easier solution than modifying our software.

Thanks!

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882981/is-there-a-way-to-have-metadata-name-longer-than-31-characters

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way (short of changing the Firebird source code yourself - it is open source, after all).