# Is there a way to have metadata name longer than 31 characters?

Tags: metadata, firebird

Is there an easy way to have metadata names longer than 31 characters in Firebird 2.1 and above? This limitation is annoying with foreign keys and view names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even in Firebird 2.5 just realease now, you can't.

You can see Firebird limit [here](https://www.ibphoenix.com/articles/art-00000323)

You can also check [firebird tracker](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-749) and vote for this request

Comment: This limitation is not easy one to get rid off. Because changing of metadata name length will require change in client interface. Thus all existing apps would require recompilation.

Comment: BTW, Oracle has similar limitation too and no one seems to complain.

Comment: Thanks for the precision and sorry if i sounded aggressive it was not my intention...

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to register on Firebird tracker and vote for this request

it's one of the top 10 feature request voted so it's on the developer's radar

http://www.firebirdnews.org/?p=4968